# "nohup sudo ..." does not prompt for passwd and does nothing

Tags: shell, sudo, background-process, nohup

When I run

```
nohup sudo myscript.sh &
```

I only get something like

```
[1] 1220
```

in return and do not get prompted for a password.  The process does not start either.

I want to run this script in the background and it needs to be run under sudo.

Anybody guess what I am doing wrong?  Using OSX Mountain Lion (Darwin).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting `sudo` in background. I see two ways to solve this problem:

1. remove the ampersand, enter your password and then pause the task with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then run `bg` so the job resumes running in the background ;
2. dirty workaround: do a dummy `sudo` before (like `sudo ls`), then launch your `nohup` command, and it won't ask for your password again and will run anyway.

Comment: i like the "dirty workaround"...

Comment: He could also launch it in screen instead of backgrounding it.

Answer (score 9):

`sudo` cannot prompt you for a password and read it because it is executing in the foreground. Run `sudo` in the foreground and arrange for it to run your program in the background.

```
sudo sh -c 'nohup myscript.sh &'
```

Comment: Beautiful, no workarounds required, this should be the accepted answer if anyone Googling comes across this. Does exactly what I needed it to do.